# Android transfer bundles and place objects in listview

Tags: android, arrays, listview, bundle

I want to create a listview populated with items I have transferred to this activity via bundles. I am completely new at this so I have no idea how. This is where I am so far:

```
    public class Viewer extends ListActivity { 
/** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    final String name = b.getString("name");
    Bundle a = getIntent().getExtras();
    final String number = a.getString("number");

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, DETAILS)); 
    ListView lv = getListView(); 
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true); 
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
          int position, long id) { 
        // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(), 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
      } 
    }); 
} 
static final String[] DETAILS = new String[] { 
    name, number
  }; 
}
```

I want to make strings "name" and "number" be in the list, but I get the error "cannot be resolved to a variable" when I place them at

```
    static final String[] DETAILS = new String[] { 
    name, number
  }; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **static final String[] DETAILS** be created when the class is loaded. But **final String name = b.getString("name");** will be executed later, when onCreate() is called.

This should work:

```
static String[] DETAILS;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    final String name = b.getString("name");
    Bundle a = getIntent().getExtras();
    final String number = a.getString("number");


    DETAILS = new String[] {name, number};

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, DETAILS)); 
    ListView lv = getListView(); 
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true); 
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
          int position, long id) { 
        // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(), 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
      } 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering. It makes sense, but I get FC... I get a NullPointerException apparently with ArrayAdapter. any idea?

Comment: if i change DETAILS = new String[] {name, number}; to DETAILS = new String[] {"something"};, it works. so it must be a problem with the transfer of data to the DETAILS array?

Comment: Yes. If a.getString(xy) returns null the ArrayAdapter will create a NullPointerException because of a null value in the DETAILS array.

Comment: Thats strange. Post the log from logcat.

Comment: Ok it only works with number. I have put my code for bundling above. Is this the right way?

Comment: Yep I was being dumb with the bundling part. Thanks alot Herrmann!